# fopen() Для создания .html файлов

Tags: php

для проекта делаю загрузку файлов с расширением .html . Пока что вышло от так, но оно не создает файл вообще. Ошибок нету, все нормально, все проверки проходит. Подскажите что делать, как изменить строчку с fopen() для того чтобы создавался файл?

```
    function fileUploadChecker() {

    global $connection;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = array();
        // масив назв строк, які треба перевірити:
        $array = array('file_name','file_content');
        // перевіряємо кожну строку на пустоту:
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            if (checkString($_POST[$value]) == false) {
                $errors [] = 'Запишіть Ваш '.$value.'!';
            }
        }  
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
            $file_content = $_POST['file_content'];
            $file = fopen('W:\domains\super-fizuka.com\view\docs'.$file_name.'.html', "w");
            fwrite($file, $file_content);
            fclose($file);
        } else {
            echo '<div style = "color = red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте `is_dir('W:\domains\super-fizuka.com\view\')` и `is_writable('W:\domains\super-fizuka.com\view\')`

Comment: Все нормально, все все вернуло 1. Но этот код не создает файл.

Comment: Проверь наличие файла: `file_exists(path)`

Comment: Нету файла, по всякому проверял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несколько моментов:

1. `\` в маршрутах - это зло. Замените на `\\` или `/`

[PHP Manual - fopen:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

> On the Windows platform, be careful to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file, or use forward slashes.

(когда писал ответ, сначала поставил слэши в кавычках, так stackoverflow заменил двойной обратный слэш на одинарный :)

2. `docs` - это часть имени файла или имя каталога? Если это каталог, то добавьте слэш в конец: `\\docs\\'.`
3. Проверьте значение параметра **open_basedir**:
   [Description of core php.ini directives - open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)
4. Судя по букве диска "W" - это присоединенный сетевой диск. Если это так, то могут быть проблемы с его видимостью у процесса Вашего веб-сервера. Попробуйте для начала писать на локальный диск, в папку с коротким 8.3 именем, например "C:/Temp"

Comment: Ни в какую. Не создается ни с слешами, ни в другую папку. Я уже не понимаю что делать.

Comment: Я уже делал разные вещи с директорией W, так что там никаких не должно быть проблем. Щас проверил что после фопена ничего не работает, то есть редиректы и так дальше после фопена не работают, ничего я не понимаю

Comment: Я обновил ответ - проверьте еще несколько пунктов

Comment: Из за моей невнимательности я немного в скрипте написал не то, когда я его переделал, оно не работало, воспользовался слешами и все заработало. Спасибо большое!